# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression in jstl using Spring-MVC

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, jstl

I have created Spring 3.0 application where after Login user get displayed jsp  page as "temp.jsp".

In temp.jsp I am using below code (using JSTL code in jsp)

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 

"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<% String[] name = {"Hello", "you", "are", "using", "jstl", "in", "jsp"};
request.setAttribute("name", name);
%>
<html>
<body bgcolor="#FFFFCC">
i m here <BR>
<c:forEach items="${name}" var="itemName">
${itemName}
<br />
</c:forEach>
</body>
</html>
```

When I comment the code from`<c:forEach` to `</c:forEach`, the jsp gets executed (display output as **i m here**), however when I uncomment the bolded code of lines, I get error as shown below

```
 HTTP ERROR 500
 Problem accessing /springmvcDepartment/loginForm.html. Reason: 

javax/el/ValueExpression

Caused by:
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/el/ValueExpression
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3713)
at     org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2120)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1599)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2219)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:456)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3305)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ValueExpression
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
... 66 more

Caused by:
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.el.ValueExpression
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:401)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppClassLoader.loadClass(WebAppClassLoader.java:363)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getPublicDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetMethodInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$TagHandlerInfo.<init>(Generator.java:3713)
at  org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.getTagHandlerInfo(Generator.java:2120)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator$GenerateVisitor.visit(Generator.java:1599)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$CustomTag.accept(Node.java:1441)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visitBody(Node.java:2213)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Visitor.visit(Node.java:2219)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Root.accept(Node.java:456)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Node$Nodes.visit(Node.java:2163)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Generator.generate(Generator.java:3305)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:198)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:295)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:276)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:264)
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:563)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:303)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:314)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:264)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:327)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Dispatcher.forward(Dispatcher.java:126)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:238)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:250)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1060)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:798)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
at  org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:563)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:390)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerList.handle(HandlerList.java:49)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:939)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.java:228)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
```

I am using Eclipse & J2EE Preview Server!!!

I tried removing/adding jar files as suggested on few forums, but NO LUCK :(

Thanks in advance for help!!!

NOTE : Actually I want to display the mysql data, but before that I want to check the JSTL code that I am using and hence I am testing the above code of jstl (temp.jsp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is jar conflict, If you remove jsp-api.2.0 from your web-inf/lib that should solve the problem. I am looking at jsp-api-2.1.jar file and I see that javax.el.ValueExpression is packaged in this jar and the same class is part of tomcats library jar (el-api.jar).

**UPDATE**

I did not realize that you are using j2ee preview server, Here are the things you need to do for your code to work

- You need to use older version of jstl jar, I say use jstl-1.1.2.jar
- Since java preview server does not provide support for el, You need to add [javax.el.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/STUVWXYZ/Downloadjavaxeljar.htm) to your web-inf/lib folder

Comment: I removed jsp-api.2.0 from WEB-INF/lib folder but still same error :(

Also I am not using Tomcat Server... Server that I am using is J2EE Server... please suggest if I need to add/remove files in/from common/WEB-INF lib folder...

Thanks

Comment: Let me know which jar files do we need to add for JSTL code to run?

I will add those files only and check whether it works or not....

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you try

```
<c:out value="${itemName}" />
```

instead?

Comment: same error...

Note that when I run same code in Netbeans which was created as Dynamic Web Project >> JSF it shows output....

Is there some jar file problem ? Please let me know if you need jar files details that I have in my lib....

Comment: in WEB-INF/lib below is what I have

    commons-logging-1.1.1

    jsp-api-2.0

    jstl-1.2

    junit-4.3.1

    mysql-connector-java-5.0.5

    org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

    org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A

Comment: and in common libraries below is what I have

commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
junit-4.3.1.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.0.5.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A
standard.jar